# Segmentation fault on EnumMonitors WinAPI

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a code to check if my virtual printer is installed, for this i'm using the EnumMonitors winapi, the code compiles, but when i try to run my program, it crashes.
Debugging my program, i got Segmentation fault error at this line: `EnumMonitors(NULL, 0, (LPBYTE)buffer, sizeof(buffer), &capacity, &returned);`
In the .pro file i added `LIBS += "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\WinSpool.Lib"`
What i can do to make the EnumMonitors WinAPI work?

My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winspool.h>

void Enum()
{
    char buffer[4096];
    DWORD capacity;
    DWORD returned;
    QString monitorname = "Redirected Port";

    /*Program crashes here*/ EnumMonitors(NULL, 1, (LPBYTE)buffer, sizeof(buffer), &capacity, &returned);

    MONITOR_INFO_1 *mi = (MONITOR_INFO_1*)buffer;
    for (uint i = 0; i < returned; i++)
    {
        if (QString::fromWCharArray(mi[i].pName) == monitorname)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

#### Edit: I've updated my code from 0 to 1 as second argument

Comment: Is there a reason why you seem to intentionally not follow the instructions on how to use `EnumMonitors`? (i.e., passing 0 for `Level`, and not calling it initially with `cbBuf` set to 0 to determine the required buffer size)

Comment: Calling it once to determine the required size is optional, not required.  But yes, the level does need to be set correctly.

Comment: You may want to set the initial values of `capacity` and `returned` to 0. No indeterminate values is always a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which compiler are you using?  When I try your code as-is in C++Builder, `EnumMonitors()` does not crash and returns an `ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL` error as expected.  That makes me think that maybe your compiler is not declaring `EnumMonitors()` correctly, mismanaging the call stack, for instance.

Comment: I'm working on Qt Creator with Qt 4.8.1 and MinGW as compiler

Comment: So there is a problem with the way Qt/MinGW interacts with `EnumMonitors()` at runtime. That still suggests to me that likely MinGW's declaration of `EnumMonitors()` is wrong, such as if it is missing the calling convention, for instance.

Comment: MinGW's headers and libraries are highly incomplete, and probably outdated. I've found Cygwin to be more WinAPI-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

The following commented code seems to work with VS2010 SP1 (VC10).

Follow the comments for an idea on how to call the `EnumMonitors()` API.

Basically, in a first call you ask for the output buffer size, [calling `EnumMonitors()` with `cbBuf` set to zero.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Then you properly size a `std::vector` with proper output buffer size, and pass the address of the first byte in the vector (using `std::vector::data()`) to a second call to `EnumMonitors()`, to fill the output buffer with `MONITOR_INFO_1` structures.

(Note that `std::vector` will *automatically* release its own allocated memory on function exit, both on success path and on failure exception-throwing paths.)

```
#include <exception>        // for std::exception
#include <iostream>         // for std::wcout, std::wcerr, std::endl
#include <sstream>          // for std::ostringstream
#include <stdexcept>        // for std::runtime_error
#include <vector>           // for std::vector
#include <windows.h>        // Win32 SDK main header
#include <winspool.h>       // for EnumMonitors()
using namespace std;

void ThrowOnApiFailure(const char* apiName, DWORD errorCode)
{
    ostringstream errorMessage;
    errorMessage << apiName << "() failed with error code " << errorCode;
    throw runtime_error(errorMessage.str());    
}

void PrintMonitors()
{
    static const int kMonitorInfoLevel = 1; // for MONITOR_INFO_1

    // Ask output buffer size
    DWORD bufferSize = 0;
    DWORD infoCount = 0;
    ::EnumMonitors(
        nullptr, 
        kMonitorInfoLevel,
        nullptr,
        0,          // ask buffer size
        &bufferSize,
        &infoCount);
    DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
    if (error != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        ThrowOnApiFailure("EnumMonitors", error);
    }   

    // Size output buffer
    vector<BYTE> buffer(bufferSize);

    // Fill buffer with monitor info
    if ( ! ::EnumMonitors(
        nullptr,
        kMonitorInfoLevel,
        buffer.data(),
        buffer.size(),
        &bufferSize,
        &infoCount       
        ) )    
    {
        error = ::GetLastError();
        ThrowOnApiFailure("EnumMonitors", error);
    }

    // Print monitor info
    const MONITOR_INFO_1 * monitorInfo = 
        reinterpret_cast<const MONITOR_INFO_1*>(buffer.data());    
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < infoCount; i++)
    {
        wcout << monitorInfo[i].pName << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        PrintMonitors();    
    }
    catch(const exception& e)
    {
        wcerr << "\n*** ERROR: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check that `EnumMonitors()` is actually returning an `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` error before using the returned buffer size. It could fail for other reasons.

Comment: No, you need to make sure that it really is ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.

Comment: Yes, on the first call, not the second.  The buffer size will not be valid if the first call fails with any error other than `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in "0" for the second parameter.  It should 1 (or 2).

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Level [in] The version of the structure pointed to by pMonitors.
>
> This value can be 1 or 2.